# 18.04, apt-get install stuck @ 100%, "Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php7.2"

Tags: 18.04

On an azure 18.04 LTS VM
I spin up the machine and right off the shelf execute the following:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wordpress php libapache2-mod-php mysql-server php-mysql
```

Progress gets up to 100% (bunch of hashtags and a single period at end in the brackets) and hangs there, here are the last couple lines output:

> Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.3) ...

> Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php7.2 (7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.7) ...

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up in the same situation:

```
"Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php7.2 (7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.7) ...

Too long with no output (exceeded 10m0s): context deadline exceeded"
```

Re-ran the installation and it worked. No idea either what goes on with this.

Ubuntu 18.04